# Make php news list on separate columns

Tags: php, html, function, zurb-foundation

So I have this code

```
$news_per_page = 30;
 $news_per_columns = $news_per_page / 3;
 $lower_bound = ($current_page * $news_per_page) - $news_per_page + 1;
$upper_bound = $current_page * $news_per_page;

echo '<div class="large-4 columns">';
echo list_news ($id_category,
                $lower_bound,
                $upper_bound,
                NULL,
                ( IsSet($_GET['title_subtitle']) && $_GET['title_subtitle'] != "" ? $_GET['title_subtitle'] : NULL ),
                ( IsSet($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] != 0 ? $_GET['category'] : NULL ),
                ( IsSet($_GET['datefrom_m']) && $_GET['datefrom_m'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['datefrom_d']) && $_GET['datefrom_d'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['datefrom_y']) && $_GET['datefrom_y'] != '' ? strtoupper($_GET['datefrom_m']).' '.$_GET['datefrom_d'].' '.$_GET['datefrom_y'] : NULL),
                ( IsSet($_GET['dateto_m']) && $_GET['dateto_m'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['dateto_d']) && $_GET['dateto_d'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['dateto_y']) && $_GET['dateto_y'] != '' ? strtoupper($_GET['dateto_m']).' '.$_GET['dateto_d'].' '.$_GET['dateto_y'] : NULL));

  echo '</div>';
```

My questions is how can I make so that the list news function displays on 3 columns. At the moment this code displays 30 news on a `large-4` `column` one under another.

Comment: Not enough informations to give you easy solution. Is 'large-4 columns' a part of any css framerwork? Are there other predefined classes like this that you could use? What is definition of 'large-4 columns' classes? Finally have you tried 'large-3 columns'? :P

Comment: large-4 columns is part of foundations 6 framework, also $lower_bound is from witch news id to start and $upperbound is where it stops displaying.

Answer (score 1):

The grid layout for Foundation is like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
</div>
```

The code you are supplying shows only a single column and no row.  If you want to have 3 columns then you will need to populate all three columns and have a row container around them.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns">News Item 1</div>
  <div class="large-4 columns">News Item 2</div>
  <div class="large-4 columns">News Item 3</div>
</div>
```

---

No seeing you entire code you could do something like this,

```
echo "<div class='row'><div class='large-4 columns'>";
for( $i = 1; $i < 31; $i++ )
{
  print "news";
  if( $i == 10 || $i == 20 )
  {
    echo "</div><div class='large-4 columns'>";
  }
}
echo "</div>";
```

This should place "news" 10 times into each column, all of which would then be inside a single row.

Comment: I do have the row div in another files and that file is importing this code inside the row. so go any idea how can i do that while or for function to display 30 news 10 on each columns ?

Comment: @FarcasAlexandru I have updated my answer, hope it sheds some light.

Comment: Then I am sorry but I have no idea what you are asking for now.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in docs of foundations 6 framework (https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html)
this is how grid layout is supposed to look:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>
```

Now your code prints something like this:

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
    <!-- NEWS -->
    <!-- NEWS -->
    <!-- NEWS -->
</div>
```

So what you need to do is a loop for printing out news in series of 3 wrapped in element with a 'row' class.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this but is not stopping when reaches to 30 post on page.
I starts displaying all my 5000+ news on 3 columns

```
  $news_per_page = 30;
  $news_per_columns = $news_per_page / 3;

  $lower_bound = ($current_page * $news_per_page) - $news_per_page + 1;
  $upper_bound = $current_page * $news_per_columns;

  while($news_per_page <= 30){
    echo "<div class='large-4 columns'>";
    echo list_news ($id_category,
                    $lower_bound,
                    $upper_bound,
                    NULL,
                    ( IsSet($_GET['title_subtitle']) && $_GET['title_subtitle'] != "" ? $_GET['title_subtitle'] : NULL ),
                    ( IsSet($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] != 0 ? $_GET['category'] : NULL ),
                    ( IsSet($_GET['datefrom_m']) && $_GET['datefrom_m'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['datefrom_d']) && $_GET['datefrom_d'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['datefrom_y']) && $_GET['datefrom_y'] != '' ? strtoupper($_GET['datefrom_m']).' '.$_GET['datefrom_d'].' '.$_GET['datefrom_y'] : NULL),
                    ( IsSet($_GET['dateto_m']) && $_GET['dateto_m'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['dateto_d']) && $_GET['dateto_d'] != '' && IsSet($_GET['dateto_y']) && $_GET['dateto_y'] != '' ? strtoupper($_GET['dateto_m']).' '.$_GET['dateto_d'].' '.$_GET['dateto_y'] : NULL));
      echo "</div>";

      $lower_bound = $lower_bound + $news_per_columns - 1;
      $upper_bound = $upper_bound + $news_per_columns;
    }
```